# angular single $http request, node shows two requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

A single request in angular is showing up two requests on node, one with x-auth-token as undefined and the other one with the token.

I looked deep into node eventually as result of following errors in my angular frontend (attached screenshot).

[image: frontend error][image: backenderror]

Angular Code:

```
    var self = this;
    var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
    var authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? localStorage.getItem("authToken") : Config.authToken;

    $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Auth-Token"] = authToken;

    $http.get(Config.url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        self.onResult(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data); //this is empty
        console.log(status); //stauts is 0
        console.log(headers); 
        console.log(config);
        self.onFault(data);
    });
```

Node.js

```
    var self = this;

    app.use(function(request, response, next){
        response.set("X-Powered-By", "FIC");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token");
        request.id = self.id++;
        console.log(request.id, request.url, request.headers['x-auth-token']); 
        next();
    });
```

Node Console output

```
0 '/attendees?appId=ag.casa.fico' undefined
1 '/attendees?appId=ag.casa.fico' 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbEFkZHJlc3MiOiJjcmlzdGlhbi5yYWN1QGJpcm91bGRlY3JlZGl0LnJvIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIxMDU3In0.X7rztUCDRngXLV6ZABvv7hqwzvWEJi1Nulxg4KWL-58'
```

Comment: Can you also log the http method? If this is a different host, the browser is likely issuing an OPTIONS request before the actual GET

Comment: see preflighted requests https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: yes it's OPTIONS -> `0 '/attendees?appId=ag.cas.fic' 'OPTIONS' undefined` but then question is why angular is ending up with `error` function call with status 0, anything i should log for the `response` at the end of the output?

Comment: not positive, but you may also need to add Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET to the response

Comment: can you have the network tab open before you send the request and post the results?

Comment: @David you mean `response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");`

Comment: got it, I had an alert(info) at the error handler, for some reason the error function is throwing up but then network tab in chrome is empty, i think something happens at the very initial level that's triggering the error but then it just works fine

Comment: @user2727195 the browser is probably caching results from preflight. http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/09/07/thoughts-on-the-cors-preflight-cache.html

Comment: @levi you're right, it's an error during preflight, what can we do to resolve it? Another learning my node.js is not outputting anything for this preflight request, i.e. request 0, but for request 1, `1 success`

Comment: Is your server configured to respond to the OPTIONS request?

Comment: not sure if it's configured, I'm testing locally and later it will be hosted at amazon eb, the result of FIRST request `OPTIONS` get intercepted as I've an alert on my frontend on error, that sort of halts everything and shows error in console, but if I press `OK` then the second request `GET` and it's result outputs, but then the problem is, if I ignore the error because of options request, I'm ignoring the real errors also that might arise in this error handler for the `GET` request

Comment: anything I could do in my middleware to output the `OPTIONS` request as ok so frontend doesn't show any error, and the system doesn't go through the whole request process (it's processor intensive) and if a `GET` or `POST` comes in, let it proceed or how it works out there?

Comment: saw this article guys http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-ajax-requests-between-jquery-and-node-js.htm I'm using express, can I choose not to call next in my middleware and skip the rest of the execution if it's OPTIONS, and res.end with 204, no content etc. as per the article

Comment: I'm filtering out the error handler in angular, if `data!=""` (empty string) then I'm escalating it higher

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting all your settings in an object and then passing that to the $http request

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': undefined
    },
        data: { test: 'test' },
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

See here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers